# JavaScript: how to build an "on and off" button?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am trying to build an interactive chart. I have made a svg element and when you click on it, it calls a function (it contains a chart) and changes its color. When you click on it again, then it changes back to the default color.

What I can't figure out is how to undo or uncall the function (which got called the first time the svg element was clicked). 
Can someone please tell me how I can solve this problem?

```
 /**
 * Set navigation
 * 
 * call functions
 */

nav = d3.select("#navigation");

// Add SVG canvas
svgContainer = nav.append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", 110)
    .attr("height", 300);

// Background dark gray rectangle
svgContainer.append("svg:rect")
    .attr("x",0)
    .attr("y",0)
    .attr("width",110)
    .attr("height",300)
    .style("fill", "#363a45");

// Add text to svgContainer
var text1 = svgContainer.append("svg:text")
    .text("CHART")    
    .attr("x", 5)
    .attr("y", 22.5) // 22.5
    .style("stroke-width", 1)
    .style("font-size", "150%")
    .style("fill", "#ececec")

var onOff1 = false;
// Add a rectangle to svgContainer
var rect1 = svgContainer.append("svg:rect")
    .attr("x",5)
    .attr("y",35)
    .attr("width",100)
    .attr("height",25)
    .attr("fill", "#7b8398")
  .on("click", function() {

    if( onOff1 == false) {
      onOff1 = true;

      CHARTEGYPT();

      d3.select(this)
        .style("fill","red");
    }
    else {
      onOff1 = false;

      d3.select(this)
        .style("fill", "#7b8398");
    }
  });

var lableEgypt = svgContainer.append("svg:text")
    .text("EGYPT")    
    .attr("x", 5)
    .attr("y", 43)
    // .style("stroke-width", 1)
    .style("font-size", "90%")
    .style("fill", "black");
```

Comment: It sound like jQuery `toggle()` !!

Comment: You can't uncall a function. You need to call another function (or the same function again) that undoes the changes the previous call made.

Comment: sorry i know nothing about jQuery.

Comment: i have tried to call another function(contains a different chart) but it goes under the first fuction(chart) and so it cannot be seen.

Comment: thank you all for the help! [ d3.select("#chart2").remove(); ] did the job! i have to recreate the the div element with the id="chart2" again!

Comment: If all you are doing is changing a colour in the chart, you don't actually need to redraw the whole thing.  You just need to modify the style - or CSS class - of the element involved.

Comment: No it needs to be replaced with another chart.